# Series convergence, two indices

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the functions $$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{n^2\text{ }(-1)^{n+m}}{(n^2+m^2)^{\frac{x+1}{2}}}.
$$
and
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{nm\text{ }(-1)^{n+m}}{(n^2+m^2)^{\frac{x+1}{2}}}.$$
what's their convergence domain? Why?

Is it possible to express them in terms of well known functions?

Comment: What's your analysis of the inner sum?

Comment: My question changed a little. I think that the sum over 'm' ($f(x)$) should converge for $x>0$ at least.